# how to read the xls file of client in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, email

I have to send the emails to my user for that I created a emails and I send it.
but I have a xls which contains all the user emails id's. I have to develop in inter face where I will select that xls file, and system will read the all emails in that xls file and shows it in gridview so that I can select the needed emails and send the emails.

I don't know how to read the xls file from fileuploader.

please help me to do this.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Office's Interop on a server-side. This is not recommended as this could leave instances of Office running. Instead, you may use one of thos libraries tor ead your Excel file :

- [EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
- [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)
- [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)
- [Linq To Excel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

There are others also. [Search here for a list of Nuget extensions](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). It's a great library for reading and writing Excel files. It doesn't use the Interops, so you don't have to worry about installing Office on your server (which won't work anyway).

Comment: i have to read the xls file from client side selected by file uploader i donot have to upload it on my server

Comment: How do you expect to read the file on the server without it being on the server?

Comment: i will just get the selected file using FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream and collect it in Excel.Workbook object

Comment: but i dont know how to collect it and get the data from it.

Comment: i have make a var object as fallow
var dataObj =  FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

but i am unable to extract data from dataObj